# i am working to get messages from .net db to list?

Tags: .net, listview

i am using list view to get messages with image.
it is working fine,when i have bellow 10 messages.
size of the messages will be increased it will take to much time to load messages from . net Db.
lazy list concept is not suitable to my app.

any one please help me.

Comment: I can barely make out what you are trying to say there; what is the problem? can you perhaps try re-phrasing? It *seems* the problem is performance, but you give no indication of how your current implementation - so how can we suggest a *better* one?

Comment: show some code on what you have done. please be more elaborate. help us to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use synchronization  class  this is very usefull in download images and messages every time u can get one record use back ground u can update the ui next record download  update ui similar to lazy list concept this concept is help full